# 'The requested resource was not found on this server.' error in django-rest-framework and pythonanywhere

Tags: django, deployment, pythonanywhere

I have a simple DRF project and I want to deploy it on Pythonanywhere. I did all the desired configurations, photos of which you can see below.

But when I want to click on the uploaded photo link (bottom photo)

[this is my api with a picture link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu5rn.jpg)

I encounter a "The requested resource was not found on this server." error(bottom photo)

[this is the error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH8e2.jpg)

This is my pythonanywhere media config:

[this is my configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiYoQ.jpg)

This is my media setting in settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/pictures/'

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploaded_pictures')
```

This is my urls.py code:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('api/', include('gardesh.urls'))
]
```

This is my models.py code:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=False)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/prof',null=False, blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
    return self.owner.username

class Post(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/cover',null=False, blank=False)
    caption = models.TextField(max_length=250, null=False, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, default='no')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    auther = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='comments')
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False, auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, 
null=True, related_name='replys')
```

You can see all my code on my GitHub: https://github.com/GrandNative/Api-gardesh.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to SO! Although links might show your code, try to include the relevant snippets in your question as links might break over time. For more tips see [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

On PythonAnywhre you need to set up static files mappings on the Web app page as well. You need to go to the Static files section there and enter the same URL as MEDIA_URL in the url section (in your case, `/pictures/`) and the path from MEDIA_ROOT into the path section (the full path, including `/home/username/...`). If the rest of the setup is fine, it should work after reloading the web app. See also [this help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/).

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem,
In Python configurations, I set the URL to media,
But in the configuration file, I set it to pictures ,                                                                     
To solve the problem, these two names must be equal